# Formula for Counting recurring "Pairs"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

In the following [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SjAwGtuTjq5pNoKC768au5tTu4Twkw0R4DfQakeqzAc/edit?usp=sharing) what is the best way to go about evaluating the '**best team**' aka the *pair that keep recurring*?

```
| Winner In Event A     | Winner In Event B     |
|-------------------    |-------------------    |
| Bob                   | Alfred                |
| Bob                   | Dave                  |
| Bob                   | Alfred                |
| Jason                 | Alfred                |
| John                  | Fred                  |
| Fred                  | John                  |
| John                  | Fred                  |
| Richard               | Jason                 |
| Richard               | Bob                   |
```

In this case, I would expect it to choose **Fred & John** as they are paired 3 times and not be tied with Bob & Alfred who are only paired 2 times.

On the example above, I include the standard VLookup which I'm sure holds the key to the solution, but I'm not sure what the paired version looks like

Comment: Please decide if you want to use Google Sheets or Excel. There are a lot of differences between the two apps and solutions may not apply to both

Comment: sorry i didn't realise that they wouldn't have equivalent solutions, removed excel reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without 3rd column:

```
=INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(LEN(A1:A&B1:B), 
 IF(A1:A>B1:B, A1:A&" & "&B1:B, B1:B&" & "&A1:A), ), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc", 0)), 2, 1)
```

[image: 0]

---

full table:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(LEN(A1:A&B1:B), 
 IF(A1:A>B1:B, A1:A&" & "&B1:B, B1:B&" & "&A1:A), ), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1 
  order by count(Col1) desc
  label count(Col1)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: QUERY is an amazing function, how did I not know about it! props! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and put it in the example above, essentially create a third column like that has this type of value

```
=IF(A14>B14, A14&" & "&B14, B14&" & "&A14)
```

Which will give you something like

```
| Winner In Event A     | Winner In Event B     | Ordered Team      |
|-------------------    |-------------------    |-----------------  |
| Bob                   | Alfred                | Bob & Alfred      |
| Bob                   | Dave                  | Dave & Bob        |
| Bob                   | Alfred                | Bob & Alfred      |
| Jason                 | Alfred                | Jason & Alfred    |
| John                  | Fred                  | John & Fred       |
| Fred                  | John                  | John & Fred       |
| John                  | Fred                  | John & Fred       |
| Richard               | Jason                 | Richard & Jason   |
| Richard               | Bob                   | Richard & Bob     |
```

Then you can just count the most common value from the 3rd column which when I [googled](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5249-google-sheets-find-most-common-value.html), looked like this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(C14:C29,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(C14:C29,C14:C29)),COUNTIF(C14:C29,C14:C29),0)))
```

Comment: You can use `=INDEX(C14:C29,MODE(MATCH(C14:C29,C14:C29)))` for that

Comment: thanks, that works, but it seems to struggle if it has empty cells, any idea why? I've popped it on the spreadsheet as 'alt going to 29'